# Session based middleware not working when StartSession is enabled

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

My middleware code:

```php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next) {
    if ($request->isMethod('get') && (!$request->hasSession() || $request->session()->pull('framed', false) == false)) {
        return response()->view('dashboard.frame');
    }

    $response = $next($request);

    if ($response instanceof RedirectResponse && $request->hasSession()) {
        $request->getSession()->flash('framed', true);
    }

    return $response;
}
```

This works unless I have `Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession` in my global middleware in my Kernel. The problem is that I need `StartSession` for other aspects of my site to work. Does anybody know why this would be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! The problem was that I had `StartSession` in both `$middlewareGroups['web']` and `$middleware`.